# Warning messages appear when using the NSSharingServicePicker class

Tags: swift, macos

> 2018-05-03 18:31:54.879424+0800 writer[5656:137819] warning: illegal
>   subclass SHKRemoteView instantiating; client should use only
>   NSRemoteView (    0   ViewBridge
>   0x00007fff7a0cabff -[NSRemoteView _preSuperInit] + 195    1   ViewBridge
>   0x00007fff7a0caf83 -[NSRemoteView initWithFrame:] + 25    2   ShareKit
>   0x00007fff763b7aa5 -[SHKRemoteView initWithOptionsDictionary:] + 161
>     3   ShareKit                            0x00007fff76396fbd
>   **38-[SHKSharingService performWithItems:]_block_invoke_4 + 1347  4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019eacfe
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019e2ddf _dispatch_client_callout + 8     6   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001019eee59 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 549    7
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff5515bc69
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff5511de4a __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2586    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff5511d1a3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483   10  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff54405d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286    11  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff54405b06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613   12  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff54405884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   64    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff526b8a73
>   _DPSNextEvent + 2085  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff52e4ee34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent)
>   _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044     15  AppKit                              0x00007fff526ad885 -[NSApplication
>   run] + 764    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff5267ca72
>   NSApplicationMain + 804   17  writer111
>   0x00000001002adf9d main + 13  18  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff7d437015 start + 1  19  ???
>   0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3 )

Although it works well, this warning message annoyed me, and I hope it will disappear.

A very simple method, but it has such a warning.

```
let sharingService = NSSharingServicePicker(items: ["111"]);
sharingService.show(relativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender, preferredEdge: .minX);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm don't know the reason for the warning, but I was able to silence it by showing the picker on the new runloop:

```
let sharingService = NSSharingServicePicker(items: ["111"]);
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), execute: {
    sharingService.show(relativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender, preferredEdge: .minX)
})
```

Comment: Are you putting the share info inside your own `NSViewController` that appears as an `NSPopover` that you are using to display the share options?

Comment: Wait, never mind. I thought you were using the CloudKit sharing popup. This is different. :)